# ошибки при подключении к репозиторию через SSH

Tags: git

я сейчас с ума сойду, объясните что не так!!
ОС: windows 10. все команды прописывал через GitBash.

- создал SSH ключи через `ssh-keygen`. проверил их наличие. лежат в папке `.ssh`
- включил ssh-agent через `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
- добавил ключ в ssh-agent через `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
  скопировал публичный ключ (id_rsa.pub) в свой профайл GitHub
  пытаюсь подключиться к репозиторию. ошибка:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь просто проверить соединение с gitHub. ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же сравнил отпечаток моего открытого ключа через `ssh-add -l -E md5`. полностью совпадает с отпечатком ключа, который добавлен в профиле GitHub.

что не так?????

Comment: Т.е. вы ни разу не прочитали вопрос “Are you sure …?”

Comment: @AlexeyTen
если это был вопрос аля "нажал ли я Yes", то мой ответ "да".

Comment: Нужно не нажать, а набрать на клавиатуре

Comment: @AlexeyTen
ох лол. я не знаю кто Вы, но это было божественно (не сарказм).
сработало. я, почему-то, думал, что Enter по дефолту соглашаеться.
еще раз спс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответьте `yes` на вопрос: `A u sure u want to continue connecting.`

Comment: сработало.
низкий поклон и прошу прощение за мою необразованость.
мне всегда казалось, что Enter по умолчанию работает как "yes".

Comment: Нет. Enter - значение по умолчанию. В данном случае, ради вашей безопасности, по умолчанию - это "нет".

Comment: тогда вопрос на будущее.
в linux Enter по дефолту так же имеет значение "no"?

Comment: Как я и сказал выше - это значение "по умолчанию". Что автор программы имел в виду под: "по умолчанию" - обычно указывается в скобочках, или документации. Для Linux хорошая практика - это сначала прочитать туториал. Большинство вопросов тогда отпадает.